# Add an opening brace to the beginning of a list in tcl

Tags: escaping, tcl, special-characters, output-formatting

I am trying to find the Cartesian product of two sets in tcl. My logic is ready, but I need to beautify the output and put an opening brace at the beginning of the list. I am able to append at the end by using **append** command, but it is throwing up error while doing so for the beginning of the list. Following is the code :

```
set a {0 1}
set b {1 2 3}
set s {}
append s "\{"                                              ### this is where the problem is
for {set i 0} { $i < 2 } {incr i} {
         for {set j $i} { $j < 2 } {incr j} {
                  set x "([lindex $a $i],[lindex $b $j])"
                  lappend s "$x,"
                  
         }
         if {$j == 2} {
                  set x "([lindex $a $i],[lindex $b $j])"
                  lappend s "$x"
               }
      }
      append s }
      puts $s
```

Now using

```
append s "\{"
```

gives

```
unmatched open brace in list
```

On the other hand, using

```
append s "\\{"
```

gives the following output :

```
\{ (0,1), (0,2), (0,3) (1,2), (1,3)}
```

Is there a way I can remove the first slash and the space between the opening brace and the first parenthesis?

Comment: You are trying to build a string, not a list. So better use string commands such as `append`, rather than a list command like `lappend`. That avoids magic quoting to happen when printing the result.

Comment: Alternatively, build the list and put it in braces at the end: `puts "{[join $s]}"`

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Cartesian+product

Comment: Hah! Two very similar answers…

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of using a list is that you can easily join it with commas in between, so you don't have to resort to treating the last element special, like you are doing. Putting the whole thing in braces is most easily done at the end, after joining the list:

```
set a {0 1}
set b {1 2 3}
set s {}
for {set i 0} {$i < 2} {incr i} {
    for {set j $i} {$j < 3} {incr j} {
        set x "([lindex $a $i],[lindex $b $j])"
        lappend s $x
    }
}
puts "{[join $s ", "]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off building the output as a list that you then convert to a string:

```
set a {0 1}
set b {1 2 3}

# The list of cells to appear in the output
set cells {}
# [foreach] is nicer than [for]/[lindex]
foreach i $a {
    foreach j $b {
        # Format a single cell
        lappend cells "($i,$j)"
    }
}
# Produce the result string with [string cat] and [join]
set result [string cat "{" [join $cells ", "] "}"]
puts $result
```

Comment: It says :


`unknown or ambiguous subcommand "cat": must be bytelength, compare, equal, first, index, is, last, length, map, match, range, repeat, replace, reverse, tolower, totitle, toupper, trim, trimleft, trimright, wordend, or wordstart
    while executing
"string cat "{" [join $cells ", "] "}""
    invoked from within
"set result [string cat "{" [join $cells ", "] "}"]"
    (file "tt.tcl" line 14)`

Am I missing any package or is it a version issue?

Comment: I considered using `foreach` in my answer, until I noticed that the inner loop is supposed to start at element $i instead of 0. Then I decided to stay closer to the original code.

Comment: @SaranshChoudhary What version of tcl are you using?

Comment: For `string cat` you need Tcl 8.6.3 or later. (I'm not entirely sure about the .3. It was added in some patch level on top of 8.6)

Comment: @Shawn I am using 8.5

Comment: Checking the release notes, I found that `string cat` first appeared in Tcl 8.6.2.

Comment: Using 8.5? Might be worth trying to move to using the current production releases instead; 8.6 is in its extended support phase, which means that it's only really getting security fixes in any timely fashion (and not too many of those, thankfully).

Comment: In older Tcl, `[string cat "{" [join $cells ", "] "}"]` can also be written `"{[join $cells {, }]}"`, but I don't think that's quite as clear as to what is happening.